# The difference between two independent geometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y \sim \text{Geometric}(p)$

I'm trying to find the distribution of $V$ where $V=(X+Y)(X-Y)$.

I know that $(X+Y)$ is the negative binomial distribution. How do I find the distribution of $X-Y$?

Comment: Are X and Y independent?  If so let Z=-Y and find the distribution of X+Z..  The distribution of V is the hard part.

Comment: You could use moment generating functions or characteristic functions, since if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with characteristic functions $\phi_X(t)$ and $\phi_Y(t)$ then the characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(-t)$.  But I am not sure this really helps: you actually want the distribution of $X^2-Y^2$,

Comment: Could you explicitly add Geometric( p )?.  Wikipedia shows more than one version of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not independent, knowledge of the distribution of $X-Y$ does not directly help even though you know how $X+Y$ is distributed.

It is worth mentioning that $V$ has a very complicated distribution, for the reason that it requires the solution to the Diophantine equation $$x^2 - y^2 = v$$ in nonnegative integers $(x,y)$ for some fixed nonnegative integer $v$.

For instance, if $v = 395$, this admits the solution set $(x,y) \in \{(42, 37), (198,197)\}$.  Yet when $v = 396$, there are three solutions; for $v = 397$ there is one solution, and $v = 398$ has no solutions.  How you'd express this behavior in a single elementary closed-form formula is not obvious to me and does not appear tractable.